# I have a problem with strapi-template installation.It can't install with any github URL and i also try with new githuburl as well

Tags: strapi

[Error: ⛔️ Template installation failed: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "npm install @strapi/starters-and-templates@1.0.0 --no-save --silent"]
at createProject (c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules@strapi\generate-new\lib\create-project.js:82:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async createQuickStartProject (c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules@strapi\generate-new\lib\create-quickstart-project.js:23:3)
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: c:\root\yarn\packages\bin\create-strapi-app
Arguments: backend --quickstart --template https://github.com/strapi/starters-and-templates
Directory: D:\nextjs-strapi-blog
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problems, following Strapi's tutorials, but I find out later that Strapi, since v4, changed the way how to create environment from template.

Correct and functional way is use commands shown in readme files in repository  https://github.com/strapi/starters-and-templates.

**For example for blog template:**

```
# Using Yarn
yarn create strapi-app my-app-name --template blog
# Or using NPM
npx create-strapi-app my-app-name --template blog
```

Comment: Using npx worked for me.