# Installing strapi

Tags: next.js, strapi

I am using yarn as my package manager . I am trying to install strapi project but there is always this error.

```
C:\Users\Asus\blog-strapi>yarn create strapi-app backend --quickstart --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-blog
yarn create v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-strapi-app@4.0.5" with binaries:
      - create-strapi-app
Creating a quickstart project.
Creating a new Strapi application at C:\Users\Asus\blog-strapi\backend.
Creating files.
Error: ⛔️ Template installation failed: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "npm view https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-blog name version --silent"


    at createProject (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\lib\create-project.js:82:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async createQuickStartProject (C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\lib\create-quickstart-project.js:23:3)
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-strapi-app
Arguments: backend --quickstart --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-blog
Directory: C:\Users\Asus\blog-strapi
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a problem with strapi-template installation.It can't install with any github URL and i also try with new githuburl as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617838/i-have-a-problem-with-strapi-template-installation-it-cant-install-with-any-git)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a template when you create strapi, you do not need to pass the `--quickstart` tag

Here are some examples with using the template

```
# Shorthand
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template strapi/blog

# Shorthand with username omitted since it defaults to strapi
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template blog

# Full GitHub URL
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-blog
```

Source: [Strapi Doc Template Install](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the `--quickstart` tag, according to [strapi doc](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/templates.html), the command to create new project with a template goes like this:

`yarn create strapi-app my-project --template <template-github-name>`

In these examples, the template-github-name argument can have different forms:

- A shorthand. If a Github user named paul has a repository called strapi-template-restaurant, then the shorthand would be paul/restaurant. It only works if the repository's name starts with strapi-template-.
- A URL. Just paste the URL of your GitHub repository. It works even if the repository is not prefixed by strapi-template-.

When using a shorthand, if the username is omitted, the CLI assumes it's strapi. So the following commands are equivalent:

```
# Shorthand
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template strapi/blog

# Shorthand with username omitted since it defaults to strapi
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template blog

# Full GitHub URL
yarn create strapi-app my-project --template https://github.com/strapi/strapi-template-blog
```

here is a [list of strapi templates](https://github.com/strapi/awesome-strapi#starters--templates) that you can use for your project

Answer (score 0):

Installation steps:

1. type
   **npx create-strapi-app@latest project-Name --quickstart**

In place of "project-Name", you have to mention your own project name

2. It will install the complete Quickstart modules on its own and will Open the Browser window, where you have to register an account or login
3. Make sure that you have the correct version of node at the current date the node version requirement is lesser that 18.x.x

To run the Strapi again
type **npm run develop**

In your case you don't need to use **--quickstart** while installing the same